mark postgres query as to-be-killed-in-case-of-a-deadlock
Sometimes, when I do DDL such as replacing several materialized views and views in one transaction, I cause trouble in the system as deadlocks happen and production queries are killed. Is there a way to tell postgres that in case of a deadlock I want MY query to be killed instead of it randomly picking one? I tried setting a lock_timeout on my query, but that did not help.

I think you can change lock_timeout as well as decrease deadlock_timeout at session level on the the matview replacement client, so that it's immediately halted if there's any risk of collision. If it takes long to finish the matview maintenance, this won't prevent problems with prod queries that arrived after that started and died waiting for locks held by the matview-handling session.

You could refresh and reindex both concurrently - that way it's Postgres job to run that in the background, sneak around locks and try not to disturb anyone. But if you're really replacing not just refreshing existing objects, it can be concurrent all it wants but initially, right after dropping the old ones and defining the new, there's no indexes to rely on and the matview remains unpopulated until it's finished, concurrently or otherwise.

If you explained why you're modifying/swapping out views and matviews on the fly it could turn out you could maybe avoid that completely, with partitioning or inheritance for example.

@Zegarek thank you for your input and the info on deadlock_timeout
